# SBT not removing previously downloaded versions

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm running Scala 2.11 with SBT and I ran into a problem where, a dependency that I'm importing fresh into my project, has a conflict with another one already in the project which happens to be used by the newly one.

When I say conflict, I mean different classes which happen to implement different interfaces.

> Guava 19.0 (local lib version) doesn't seem to work with the Guava
>   version being used in that previously mentioned dependency.

And what I did to solve this problem was to update the local Guava version to 26.0-jre.

So far so good, problem solved (apparently).

After performing the code check I wanted to do for a newly created feature and seeing that everything works alright, I revert by **build.sbt** file and come back again to Guava 19.0.

I relaunch the project and the issue is no longer there. What could be going on? Shouldn't I get the previously mentioned issue?

I went into .ivy2 dir to check versions in there and all those are 19.0 (they don't even get updated to 26.0-jre or whatever in there). Hope that sheds some light.

Answer (score 1):

That is expected. Once you have dowloaded, it will be there (`.ivy2` folder) for ever. As for why your project still works fine, just because class loader load version 26 this time. So this is depends on class loader loading order which your sbt cannot guranteed. Maven also have similar problem. Usually, we need use [`exclude`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies) to remove such potential problem.  Hope this can help.

`libraryDependencies += 
  "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.15" exclude("javax.jms", "jms")`

Comment: I was expecting to remove it from .ivy2 folder, but the .jar files that I got and everything related to that seems to be 19.0 even having 26.0-jre within the build.sbt. It's pretty strange.

Comment: Just don't understand why you will want to remove from .ivy2 folder. it is your local sbt repository, not your project dependencies.